Not understanding this part of Rosen's textbook on the n-queen problem

I'm not understanding why squares Note that squares (i, j) and (i', j') are on the same diagonal if either i + i' = j + j' or i - i' = j - j'.
I understand that |i - i'| = |j - j'|, but not sure where they're getting i + i' = j + j' from. Also, is the "either... or.." and inclusive or exclusive "or" in this context?

I'm confused on why I got downvoted. Kindly if I did something wrong please let me know.

Choose $c$ and draw the graphs $x+y=c$ along with $x-y=c$ in the ordinary Cartesian plane.  I think you'll see where both equations come from.

Ohhh I think I see now! Thank you so much! I felt I would've got it had I thought about all possible diagonals.

@RobertShore So I guess that means the "either... or" is exclusive here since 2 points can't be on 2 different lines?

That's correct.

@RobertShore wait but then shouldn't it really be i + j = i' + j'?

Yes, that appears to be a mistake on the author's part.

@RobertShore Kindly just want to make sure I'm understanding carefully here, but how did you know to choose those 2 equations specifically to prove they're thing? Just want to better understand you're line of reasoning/though process.

I honestly don't know how to answer that question.

@RobertShore wait why?

@RobertShore I mean to say that for me it would be more intuitive to choose -x + c = y & x + c = y to represent the different diagonals. You get x + y = c and y - x = c, where last equation is just slightly different from your choice of x - y = c (but gives same result). I guess you were trying to match their form more, but I want to be more clear about your thinking.

I don't know how to answer the question because doing it the way I outlined was literally the first thought that occurred to me.
